# Are there any changes to IPN params with Enhanced Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

I'm using Paypal Website Payments Standard to accept recurring payments, but thinking of upgrading to "Enhanced Recurring Payments" to accept recurring payments from people without paypal accounts. I want to know, what if any are the changes to the APIs? Specifically, do the IPN messages differ at all? I can't find any information on how Enhanced Recurring Payments changes it, if at all.

If anybody knows, or can post a sample IPN for an Enhanced Recurring Payment without a PayPal account, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference of only one variable between the IPN for PayPal Payments and the Credit card Payments . For the credit IPN you will receive an extra variable "receipt_id" in addition to the other variables . I have posted the two sample IPN's below :

**ERP IPN when somebody pays via credit card option**

```
mc_gross=1.00 &protection_eligibility=Eligible &address_status=confirmed &payer_id=ZQSC4
4KE3MPNE &address_street=3710 Spring Haven Trail ada &payment_date=07:49:47 Sep 29, 2014 PDT
&payment_status=Completed &charset=UTF-8 &address_zip=07054 &first_name=Eshan &
option_selection1=Small &option_selection2=Red &option_selection3=Value for the text field &
amp;mc_fee=0.33 &address_country_code=US &address_name=Eshan agag &notify_version=3.8 &a
mp;subscr_id=I-KJR1N7DVTSFV &custom=THIS IS CUSTOM VARIABLE FOR SUBSCRIPTION &payer_status=u
nverified &business=XXXXXXXXX &address_country=United States &address_city=Pa
rsippany &verify_sign=Aw6X5vyHflgdAgaJGWvPoCJ8QoI9AGpk50cgjQn5vFFAb.keQURphbSq &payer_email=
jain@jainwain.com &option_name1=First Drop Down &option_name2=Second Drop Down &option_n
ame3=This is Text field &contact_phone=434-343-3434 &txn_id=9E162447RW023401J &payment_t
ype=instant &last_name=agag &address_state=NJ &receiver_email=XXXXXXXXXX &
payment_fee=0.33 &receiver_id=XXXXXXXXX &txn_type=subscr_payment &item_name=Passing 
custom field in subs button to see if it comes in IPN and show up in Account &mc_currency=USD &a
mp;residence_country=US &test_ipn=1 & **receipt_id=3610-4109-0310-2116** &transaction_subject
=Passing custom field in subs button to see if it comes in IPN and show up in Account &payment_g
ross=1.00 &ipn_track_id=42d902b155b6d
```

**IPN when someone pays via PayPal**

```
mc_gross=1.00 &invoice= 12345678 &protection_eligibility=Eligible &address_status=confir
med &payer_id=XXXXXXXXXX &address_street=cxas asa &payment_date=09:40:46 Sep 29, 2014
PDT &payment_status=Completed &charset=UTF-8 &address_zip=95616 &first_name=Eshan P
ersonal Test &option_selection1=Small &option_selection2=Red &option_selection3=Using th
e text field as the hidden one and also passed invoice id &mc_fee=0.33 &address_country_code
=US &address_name=Eshan Personal Test Account &notify_version=3.8 &subscr_id=I-79KEGCFRB
8V6 &custom=THIS IS CUSTOM VARIABLE FOR SUBSCRIPTION &payer_status=verified &business=XXXXXXX
&address_country=United States &address_city=FL &verify_sign=ABoC7zeo
JKOS8-FgzxlPH0pKFIpkABi1td4dId5Vndd1boMDXpvdWXfX &payer_email=XXXXXXXXX &option_n
ame1=First Drop Down &option_name2=Second Drop Down &option_name3=This is Text field &co
ntact_phone=408-767-7151 &txn_id=5LX310552A647342M &payment_type=instant &last_name=Acco
unt &address_state=FL &receiver_email=XXXXXXX &payment_fee=0.33 &receiv
er_id=XXXXXXX &txn_type=subscr_payment &item_name=Passing custom field in subs button 
to see if it comes in IPN and show up in Account &mc_currency=USD &residence_country=US &
;test_ipn=1 &transaction_subject=Passing custom field in subs button to see if it comes in IPN a
nd show up in Account &payment_gross=1.00 &ipn_track_id=80ffac6da5284
```

I have attached Screen Shot also :

[image]

Comment: A couple more questions actually, if you dont mind: Can I still refund a payment if I need to, or give a partial refund? Can I do so programmatically like I'm doing now?

Comment: Yes you can do both partial or the full refund . I did the partial refund for the above posted transaction and you can see the IPN message here :  http://screencloud.net/v/vLzl